# ssh: Allow root to login without password

Tags: openssh, sshd

i want to login via ssh without password using root account.
I have problem with /etc/ssh/sshd_config file.
I set: **PermitRootLogin without-password** and **StrctMode no** but it doesn't work (i have to enter passphrase to key)

I have Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: The accepted answer on that question is horrible, poorly written with unnecessary use of root and no information on how to transfer keys.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I agree with you 100%.  I hated what it said, and maybe I should not have put it as a duplicate.  Even the answers below are missing what you wrote.  Maybe we need to merge that question with this one?  I have done the root logins before and I have used your method so I know it works.  =)

Comment: Cant really do much by leave a comment or perhaps flag the question / answer. It has so many upvotes it would take a lot of down votes to change.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Maybe we can helpful flag your comment there to help bring attention back to that answer?  =)

Comment: Not sure why this question was down voted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the option "PermitRootLogin without-password" does not do what you think it does. This option does not allow you to log in without a password, it allows you to log in as root via any method other then password authentication.

Typically this would be ssh keys, but could include other methods such as kerberos.

Second, I highly suggest you continue to login as root with a key with a password. If you do not want to enter a password every time, add it to ssh agent. On the command line this would be `ssh-add ~/.ssh/key_name`. This is a one time entry of your key password and subsequently you do not need to enter a password.

After the above command you can simply

```
ssh root@server
```

If you want a key without a password , make a new key with an empty password on the client machine.

```
ssh-keygen
```

When it asks you for a password, just hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key without entering a password.

I suggest you give it a name rather then using the default.

You transfer the key with `ssh-copy-id` (you will need to log in to the server as root with a password to transfer the key).

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/your_key.pub root@server
```

You can then ssh in without a password

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/your_key root@server
```

Once the key is working, go ahead and disable password authentication again.